# validate period delimited numbers regex

Tags: regex

I have a tricky regex.

- numbers are is delimited by periods .
- there can be a max of 4 periods. between each period there can be 0 to 4 numbers.

valid expressions include

```
....
...
..
.
.1234.1234
..1234.1234.1234
1234.1234.1234.1234.1234 (this is the max string)
1234.1234
1234....1234
1234.1234.1234
```

invalid strings include the following

```
12345 (too many digits example)
..1234...1234 (this is 5 periods)
1234.12345 (too many digits example)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's particularly tricky... Just repeat a group of period+numbers:

```
^\d{0,4}(\.\d{0,4}){0,4}$
```

Edit: Works better with correct syntax. What's this for btw?

Edit 2: Depending on your regex flavor you may need `^$`.

Comment: awesome thanks. That works flawlessly. ya i changed it to commas and threw on the ^$.

Comment: yours is much better than mine O_o

Answer (score 1):

```
/^\d{0,4}(?!\d)(?:\.?\d{0,4}(?!\d)){0,4}$/
```

Tested in JS:

```
var r = /^\d{0,4}(?!\d)(?:\.?\d{0,4}(?!\d)){0,4}$/;

r.test('....'); // true
r.test('...'); // true
r.test('..'); // true
r.test('.'); // true
r.test('.1234.1234'); // true
r.test('..1234.1234.1234'); // true
r.test('1234.1234.1234.1234.1234'); // true
r.test('1234.1234'); // true
r.test('1234....1234'); // true
r.test('1234.1234.1234'); // true

r.test('12345'); // false
r.test('..1234...1234'); // false
r.test('1234.12345'); // false
```